# gitignore not working in python environment

Tags: python, git

I have never had a problem with .gitignore not having any effect. The only thing that I can think of is that using the python env is making the .gitignore not being found. however in the .git/info/exclude file all the exclusions work as anticipated. It doesn't matter if it's a Linux or Windows environment.

Placing the gitignore in the root of the project folder has no effect. It doesn't matter which type of environment it is (conda or pipenv). It will not work.

```
conda.bat activate envname

The below files will not be excluded in .gitignore placed in root folder. It will however work perfectly fine if included in .git/info/exclude.    

my.sqlite
*.sqlite3
*.sqlite

*.gz
*.pxi
*.csv.gz
*.json
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You say it doesn't work because...... Like, give us more details so we can figure it out (add it to the question).

Comment: What do you mean by "python environment"? Can you give dumps of examples which work as expected and which don't?

Comment: updated with some more.

Comment: The files that you consider that `.gitignore` is not working (correctly) on... they are already tracked?

Comment: no not already tracked. First file .gitignore was included already from repository creation. Then cloned from bitbucket.

Comment: What file encoding is your `.gitignore` in? What kind of line endings? Is it called `.gitignore` _exactly_, same case, no extension?

Comment: yes to all of the above. I have been using git for years and with nodejs this is absolutely no problem.